# How to make a fixed overlay in scrolledwindow?

Tags: python, gtk3

How to make a fixed overlay in scrolledwindow?
This is my code:

```py
    def create_textview(self):
        frame = Gtk.Frame()
        frame.set_label(os.path.basename(TextViewWindow.temporary(self, widget=None)))

        scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolledwindow.set_hexpand(True)
        scrolledwindow.set_vexpand(True)

        self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
        self.textview.set_editable(True)
        self.textview.connect("key-release-event", self.releaseKeys)
        self.textview.connect("key-press-event", self.key_Return)
        self.textview.connect("key-press-event", self.key_BackSpace)
        self.textview.connect("key-press-event", self.blockedKeys)

        self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
        self.OpenFile = otworzplik.OpenFile()

        # Background

        #
        overlay = Gtk.Overlay()

        pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(
            filename="kibord.png",
            width=500,
            height=160,
            preserve_aspect_ratio=True)

        image = Gtk.Image()
        image.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)

        overlay.add_overlay(image)

        overlay.add(self.textview)
        scrolledwindow.add(overlay)
        frame.add(scrolledwindow)
```

Comment: Relevant [`Gtk.Overlay.signals.get_child_position`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Overlay.html#Gtk.Overlay.signals.get_child_position)

Comment: I'm just starting to learn gtk, can I have an example, please?

Comment: ***"example, please?"***: [overlay-over-gstreamer-video-with-gtk-overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012723/cannot-overlay-over-gstreamer-video-with-gtk-overlay), [set-location-of-gtk-button-in-gtk-overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311808/how-to-set-location-of-gtk-button-in-gtk-overlay) and `c++` [example_overlay.cc](https://github.com/GNOME/gtkmm/blob/master/demos/gtk-demo/example_overlay.cc), [examples - overlay](https://github.com/gtk-rs/examples/blob/master/src/bin/overlay.rs)

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_textview(self):
    frame = Gtk.Frame()
    frame.set_label(os.path.basename(TextViewWindow.temporary(self, widget=None)))

    scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scrolledwindow.set_hexpand(True)
    scrolledwindow.set_vexpand(True)

    self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
    self.textview.set_editable(True)
    self.textview.connect("key-release-event", self.releaseKeys)
    self.textview.connect("key-press-event", self.key_Return)
    self.textview.connect("key-press-event", self.key_BackSpace)
    self.textview.connect("key-press-event", self.blockedKeys)

    self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
    self.OpenFile = otworzplik.OpenFile()

    # Obraz tła

    #
    overlay = Gtk.Overlay()

    pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(
        filename="kibord.png",
        width=300,
        height=96,
        preserve_aspect_ratio=True)

    image = Gtk.Image()
    image.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)

    # Fixed for fixed positioned overlay widgets
    fixed = Gtk.Fixed()
    overlay.add_overlay(fixed)
    overlay.set_overlay_pass_through(fixed, True)

    # Put fixed overlay
    fixed.put(image, 650, 10)


    # overlay.add(self.textview)
    overlay.add(frame)
    scrolledwindow.add(self.textview)
    frame.add(scrolledwindow)
```

it's good now, thank you for your help.